# run a command with execvp in c program

Tags: c, execvp

I want to run this command with execvp

```
gcc file1.o file2.o file3.o
```

I created a tab wich contain this :

```
char * tab = {"file1.o", "file2.o", "file3.o", NULL };
```

when I call execvp like that :

```
 execvp("gcc",tab);
```

I have this error :

```
file1.o: erreur fatale: -fuse-linker-plugin, but liblto_plugin.so not found
```

When I compile the files using :

```
gcc file1.o file2.o file3.o
```

there is no problem.

Note my program is not like that I wrote it like that to simplify. for the complete code look visit http://pastebin.com/zQ8pwmZd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first element of the `argv` array passed to `execvp` (i.e., the second argument passed to `execvp`) should be (just like with the `argv` array passed to the `main` function of any C program) the name of the program being executed, with the element after that being the first command-line argument.  Thus, `tab` should be:

```
char * tab[] = {"gcc", "file1.o", "file2.o", "file3.o", NULL };
```

Comment: @rabahRachid: If my answer solved your problem, you should accept it by clicking the checkmark underneath the voting arrows.

Comment: "char * tab = {"gcc", "file1.o", "file2.o", "file3.o", 0 };" won't compile. Do you mean "char * tab[] = {"gcc", "file1.o", "file2.o", "file3.o", 0 };" ?

Comment: yes.like I said I haven't wrote like that. It's just to simplify so I haven't paid attention to this error. Someone could tell me why tab must end with NULL. The people who wrote the function couldn't do it otherwise without adding NULL at the end!